# Add today's time to tomorrow's date js using moment.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, time, momentjs

```
const today = new Date();
const tomorrow = new Date(today);
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `add` method on moment like this:

```
const today = new Date();
const tomorrow = moment(today).add(1, 'days').toDate()
```